# Can we assign a service account to already running GCP VM using terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have requirement to assign GCP service account to GCP compute engine.
This VM is already created using terraform, Now i want to create new Serviceaccount and assign it to that running VM but i don't want to do changes in VM terraform script.

Instead i want to created different terraform script for SA and bind creation with hardcoded VM values.

Is that possible using terraform ?

```
resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  project      = "dataproc"
  account_id   = "terraform-testing-1"
  display_name = "terraform-testing-1"
}

resource "google_compute_instance_iam_binding" "vm_binding" {
  project       = "dataproc"
  zone          = "us-central1-a"
  instance_name = "gcpterraform-test-vm-1"

  role        = "roles/compute.instanceAdmin"
  members     = ["serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}"]
}
```

Comment: I expect your script will fail. You are not importing a resource, therefore Terraform will not modify the resource. If it did, your other Terraform state would become invalid. Test and let us know the result.